# How to help improve Banshee?

Tags: banshee, bug-reporting

I have had some problems running Banshee. It crashes quite often after finishing playing a song. It also jumps all over the place when playing back albums - sometimes it plays the first song twice - other times it jumps from the first song to the fourth.

How can I help pinpoint the cause of these problems? What would I need to do to be able to at least provide crash report information? I would love to help make the application better in whatever way I can.

Comment: For those specific problems, I'd make sure your Play Queue is empty, and turn off Gapless Playback in Edit > Preferences. It's not a guaranteed fix, but it's a place to start looking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In case of crashes you have to set Banshee up to create a [debug log](http://live.gnome.org/Banshee/CommonQuestions/Logs). 
Short version from the link:

`killall banshee`

`cd ~; banshee --debug 2>&1 | tee banshee-debug-log.txt`

Reproduce your problem and exit banshee and attach the resulting banshee-debug-log.txt to your bug report.

There is also a faq on [performance issues](http://live.gnome.org/Banshee/CommonQuestions/PerformanceIssues) <sub>I wonder why there is a faq about this? Isn't this admitting it is not so good?)</sub>

And finally Banshee also uses [bugzilla](http://banshee.fm/contribute/file-bugs/).

Comment: The FAQ about performance issues is a user-maintained wiki, not an admission from Banshee developers that it is not so good. Although I'm sure they wouldn't hesitate to admit that there are areas where Banshee can improve performance.